# How to move specific messages from one topic to another on demand in Pulsar (using pulsar-admin)?

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I have a requirement of moving specific messages from DLQ to RETRY queue. I want to use `pulsar-admin` for this task.
I have `message-id` for all the messages.

~note: don't want to copy and produce manually, it is error prone

Any other approach is acceptable.

Comment: Would writing a Function for this be a possibility ? (https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/functions-overview/). Setting DLQ as input-topic of the function and RETRY as output with Subscription.Earliest.

Comment: @ChristopheBornet Pulsar Functions are used on Continues streaming messages. we can definitely move messages to DLQ, but I want on-demand transfer, and that too only for specific messages.

Comment: I presume the MessageIds you have are for batch messages ? Or is batching disabled ?

Comment: Batch is Disabled

Comment: I don't think `pulsar-admin` is the proper tool for the job. IMHO, a parameterized script or some sort that takes the DLQ and RETRY topic names along with the messageIDs that then uses the Pulsar client to move the messages is a better approach.